# Having trouble with the general term of recurrence relation $g(j+1) = a g(j) + bg(j-1)$ with boundary conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I am trying to understand the general term of following recurrence relation

[image]

I rewrote it as:

$$g(j) = e^{-h}[p g(j+1) +q g(j-1)]  $$

which yields:

$$ g(j+1) = \frac{e^h}{p} g(j) - \frac{q}{p}g(j-1) $$

Then we can write the following relation:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ \frac{e^h}{p} & \frac{q}{p}  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} g(j-1) \\ g(j)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} g(j) \\ g(j+1)  \end{bmatrix}$$

Which can be rewritten as

$$A v_j = v_{j+1} $$

where

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ \frac{e^h}{p} & \frac{q}{p}  \end{bmatrix} \\ v_j=\begin{bmatrix} g(j-1) \\ g(j)  \end{bmatrix}  $$

this gives us

$$A^j v(1) = v(j+1) $$

Now, we want to find $D$ diagonal such that $B A B^{-1} = D$. That is, we want to diagonalize the matrix.

First we go for the eigen values $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$

[image]

Which are the roots of $\det (A - \lambda I ) = 0$

Once we have the roots, we find the eigenvectors:

$$A w_- = \lambda_- w_-\\
A w_+ = \lambda_- w_+$$

Choose $w_- =  (1, y_-)$ and $ w_+ =  (1, y_+)$ this gives

$$y_- = \lambda_-\\
y_+ = \lambda_+ $$

Now the basis change matrix are

$$ B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ \lambda_- & \lambda_+  \end{bmatrix} \\
B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ \lambda_- & \lambda_+  \end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

and

$$ B^-1 A B = D $$

or equivalently

$$  A  =  B D B^{-1}$$

Now we come back to the relation

\begin{align}A^j v(1) &= v(j+1) \\
 B D^j B^{-1} v(1) &= v(j+1)
\end{align}

To make the computation one needs an explicit expression of $B^{-1}$ :

$$B^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_+ & -1 \\ -\lambda_- & 1  \end{bmatrix} \det(B)^{-1} $$

Finally:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ \frac{e^h}{p} & \frac{q}{p}  \end{bmatrix}^j\begin{bmatrix} g(0) \\ g(1)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} g(j) \\ g(j+1)  \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ \lambda_- & \lambda_+  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_-^j & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_+^j  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_+ & -1 \\ -\lambda_- & 1  \end{bmatrix} \det(B)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} g(0) \\ g(1)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} g(j) \\ g(j+1)  \end{bmatrix}$$

the computations now follow:

\begin{align}g(j)& = \frac{1}{\det(B)} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1   \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_-^j & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_+^j  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_+g(0) - g(1) \\ g(1)-\lambda_-g(0)   \end{bmatrix}
\\
& = \frac{1}{det(B)}\lambda_-^j(\lambda_+g(0) - g(1)) + \lambda_+^j(g(1)-\lambda_-g(0))
\end{align}

Now we remember that $g(0) = e^{-h}g(1)$ substituting we obtain:

\begin{align}g(j)& 
 = \frac{1}{det(B)} \big(\lambda_+^j(1-\lambda_-e^{-h}) - \lambda_-^j(1-\lambda_+ e^{-h} ) \big)g(1)
\end{align}

This is almost

[image]

But how do we show that $\frac{g(1)}{det(B)} = \big(\lambda_+^z(1-\lambda_-e^{-h}) - \lambda_-^z(1-\lambda_+ e^{-h} )\big)^{-1}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to write

$$1 = g(z) =  \frac{g(1)}{det(B)} \big(\lambda_+^z(1-\lambda_-e^{-h}) - \lambda_-^z(1-\lambda_+ e^{-h} ) \big)
 $$

and conclude that

$$\frac{g(1)}{det(B)} =  \big(\lambda_+^z(1-\lambda_-e^{-h}) - \lambda_-^z(1-\lambda_+ e^{-h} ) \big)^{-1} $$